# ACF Rest Api - Categories Return Value Term Object Not working

Tags: wordpress, rest, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to return an object with values in the category but ACF only returns an array of keys.

Help?

[Example of return value & settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elicG.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have "show in REST API" turned off?

Comment: That's the setting for ACF. I used another plugin  ( REST API Helper by JasmanXcrew ) to get the REST api working.

I ended up creating my own REST Route in WordPress to solve this issue. 

Not sure why it only returns the keys though, it should return an object of values...

Comment: By the way, I have also tried to use the default show in REST Api as well and it returns an array of keys.

Answer (score 2):

ACF doesn't respect the "Return Value" selection of the field in REST API responses by default, but if you add the `acf_format=standard` query param to your request it then respects the return value option.

`/wp-json/wp/v2/post?acf_format=standard`

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/#controlling-output-format

"Additionally, if you want to default the format to standard for all response data, you can enforce this by using the acf/settings/rest_api_format filter:"

```php
add_filter( 'acf/settings/rest_api_format', function () {
    return 'standard';
} );
```